# Is PHP glob's GLOB_BRACE slow?

Tags: php, glob

I've got 2 copies of the same script, the only difference is

A)

```
$images = glob("*.*")
```

B)

```
$images = glob("*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}", GLOBAL_BRACE)
```

To me, B should run quicker as it's got less of a selection (although, on the other hand, more filtering).  But it's taking 3.64s to load, rather than A, which takes 122ms.  These were taken from Chrome's network tab in the JS console (this is an AJAX call).

I'm trying to think of something logical for the big difference, but it's the same directory, same server, same everything (just +GLOB_BRACE).

Comment: Try `microtome(true)` before and after the call for a more accurate time measurement. Including the whole HTTP stack and network transfer (?) is not useful.

Comment: use a debugger/profiler to get accurate timing at the PHP level

Comment: Use Symfony2 Finder Component: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/finder.html . This way you'll use nice OOP code and learn some good programming habits.

Comment: I've put it round the glob and it's definitely that.  It's going from 0.8secs to 3.2secs when I add the braces.

Answer (score 1):

> Is PHP glob's GLOB_BRACE slow?

No. Accessing the filesystem is.

You should really put only images in a directory, so you don't need to "glob" at all, and instead use a plain old [`opendir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php).

Comment: Doesn't really account for the difference in times I'm seeing...

Comment: You're looking just at the difference, not at the problem as a whole. My answer represents the most optimal solution, globbed or not.

Comment: The images are in a dir, but you still need to know what they are?

Comment: The keyword in my answer is **only**: if you put only images in that dir, you don't need to glob() any more. Sounds logically? Things could become even better: if you store the file list of that dir somewhere like a memcache, shared memory, or a database, you don't need to access the FS at all (well, of course, unless you really need to read the images' content, but by that time, you know precisely which image you want, so it's a targeted FS access, you don't have to "look around" any more, which is costly).

Comment: I would DB it if the images were being added via the site, but they're being created else where and being dumped in, so I don't think that would work in this case.  But if there's a better way to glob the dir (listdir in python for example), I'm all ears.

Comment: The best way (if you don't have access to the "other system" which creates the images) is to use a background process and inotify (under linux, I don't know about other systems). There are bindings for PHP and python: http://php.net/manual/en/book.inotify.php, https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify. The inotify-based service could insert data in your cache system, and in PHP you'd look in the cache first, if it's not there you can use opendir() & co. This is the solution with the most reliability and the smallest latency you can get from the programmer's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on glob implementation. If that is based on regular expressions which is run against every file it has all right to be slow (as the regular expressions are very slow). I'm surprised about 3.6 tho' how many files do you have out there?